# OpenGL: 3D Models not being rendered correctly, only rendered as 2D?

Tags: opengl, 3d, d, assimp

I am trying to load a simple octahedron using Assimp. This is what the model is supposed to look like :

[image]

However, this is what renders with my code:

[image]

Clearly, this isn't correct. I am unsure where I am at fault in my code, though I suspect it is with the OpenGL, not the Assimp code.

Here is my code:

```
    auto scene = scoped!AssimpScene(assimp,"octahedron.obj",aiProcessPreset_TargetRealtime_Fast);
auto mesh = scene.scene().mMeshes[0]; 

auto vertex = new float[mesh.mNumFaces*3*3];
auto normal = new float[mesh.mNumFaces*3*3];
int b = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < mesh.mNumFaces;i++)
{
    auto face = mesh.mFaces[i];
    for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {

         auto va  = cast(float[3])mesh.mVertices[face.mIndices[j]];
         vertex[b..b+3] = va;


         auto n  = cast(float[3])mesh.mNormals[face.mIndices[j]];
         normal[b..b+3] = n;
         b+=3;
    }
}
while(!sdl2.keyboard().isPressed(SDLK_ESCAPE))
{
    sdl2.processEvents(); 
    //clear screen
    glViewport(0, 0, width,height);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);

    glVertexPointer(3,GL_FLOAT,0,cast(const(void*))vertex);
    glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT,0,cast(const(void*))normal);


    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES,0,mesh.mNumFaces*3);
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    window.swapBuffers();

}
scene.close();
assimp.close();
}
```

The code is choppy and could be greatly improved, though I am very new to OpenGL, so I am unsure how exactly. Any advice in that regards would be greatly appreciated!

Here is the log produced at run time for reference:

```
2014-10-14T17:19:26.0681112:assimp.d:loggingCallbackAssimp:149 
info: assimp: Info,  T0: Load octahedron.obj

2014-10-14T17:19:26.0681631:assimp.d:loggingCallbackAssimp:149 
info: assimp: Debug, T0: Assimp 3.0.1262 amd64 gcc debug shared singlethreaded

2014-10-14T17:19:26.0681916:assimp.d:loggingCallbackAssimp:149 
info: assimp: Info,  T0: Found a matching importer for this file format

2014-10-14T17:19:26.0682121:assimp.d:loggingCallbackAssimp:149 
info: assimp: Info,  T0: Import root directory is './'

2014-10-14T17:19:26.0682681:assimp.d:loggingCallbackAssimp:149 
info: assimp: Info,  T0: Entering post processing pipeline

2014-10-14T17:19:26.0682903:assimp.d:loggingCallbackAssimp:149 
info: assimp: Debug, T0: GenUVCoordsProcess begin

2014-10-14T17:19:26.0683055:assimp.d:loggingCallbackAssimp:149 
info: assimp: Debug, T0: GenUVCoordsProcess finished

2014-10-14T17:19:26.0683206:assimp.d:loggingCallbackAssimp:149 
info: assimp: Debug, T0: TriangulateProcess begin

2014-10-14T17:19:26.0683351:assimp.d:loggingCallbackAssimp:149 
info: assimp: Debug, T0: TriangulateProcess finished. There was nothing to be done.

2014-10-14T17:19:26.0683503:assimp.d:loggingCallbackAssimp:149 
info: assimp: Debug, T0: SortByPTypeProcess begin

2014-10-14T17:19:26.0683655:assimp.d:loggingCallbackAssimp:149 
info: assimp: Info,  T0: Points: 0, Lines: 0, Triangles: 1, Polygons: 0 (Meshes, X = removed)

2014-10-14T17:19:26.0683812:assimp.d:loggingCallbackAssimp:149 
info: assimp: Debug, T0: SortByPTypeProcess finished

2014-10-14T17:19:26.0683975:assimp.d:loggingCallbackAssimp:149 
info: assimp: Debug, T0: GenFaceNormalsProcess begin

2014-10-14T17:19:26.0684129:assimp.d:loggingCallbackAssimp:149 
info: assimp: Info,  T0: GenFaceNormalsProcess finished. Face normals have been calculated

2014-10-14T17:19:26.0684297:assimp.d:loggingCallbackAssimp:149 
info: assimp: Debug, T0: Generate spatially-sorted vertex cache

2014-10-14T17:19:26.0684487:assimp.d:loggingCallbackAssimp:149 
info: assimp: Debug, T0: CalcTangentsProcess begin

2014-10-14T17:19:26.068466:assimp.d:loggingCallbackAssimp:149 
info: assimp: Error, T0: Failed to compute tangents; need UV data in channel0

2014-10-14T17:19:26.0684825:assimp.d:loggingCallbackAssimp:149 
info: assimp: Debug, T0: CalcTangentsProcess finished

2014-10-14T17:19:26.0684983:assimp.d:loggingCallbackAssimp:149 
info: assimp: Debug, T0: JoinVerticesProcess begin

2014-10-14T17:19:26.0685253:assimp.d:loggingCallbackAssimp:149 
info: assimp: Debug, T0: Mesh 0 (unnamed) | Verts in: 24 out: 24 | ~0%

2014-10-14T17:19:26.0685428:assimp.d:loggingCallbackAssimp:149 
info: assimp: Debug, T0: JoinVerticesProcess finished 

2014-10-14T17:19:26.0685593:assimp.d:loggingCallbackAssimp:149 
info: assimp: Info,  T0: Leaving post processing pipeline
```

Comment: Your code looks a lot like D, why did you tag it as C++?

Comment: It is D, my mistake! - I removed the tag

Answer (score 1):

Theres lots of things you are not doing, openGL is much lower level than you think, you have to specify matricies and lighting etc even with legacy GL.

Recommend the tutorial at http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/index.html

Comment: Ah, Interesting thank you! I was following this tutorial http://nickthecoder.wordpress.com/2013/01/20/mesh-loading-with-assimp/ and he did not specify matrices or lighting. I will read that link, thanks!

Comment: You definitely don't want to use legacy GL, although modern is slightly harder to get into, once you figure out the basics its better in every way.

Comment: @Rishub: Well, that tutorial is about mesh loading with assimp, not about rendering with opengl.

Answer (score 0):

You do not do any camera transformations. If you want a quick fix you can use gluLookAt, but I recommend  not using deprecated OpenGL. Here's a good tutorial: https://open.gl/

Comment: Thanks! very fitting domain name